# Not all socket data sent before shutdown is received

Tags: perl, sockets

I am writing Perl scripts to send strings between a client and server over TCP. The connection is made but data send from the client isn't received.

Full code for the server

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Socket;

my $port = 8021;
my $proto = getprotobyname ('tcp');
my $server = "localhost";

socket (SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
    or die "Can't open socket: $!";

bind (SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in ($port, inet_aton ($server)))
    or die "Can't bind $server:$port: $!";

listen (SOCKET, 5)
    or die "Can't listen on $server:$port: $!";

my $client_addr;

while ($client_addr = accept (NEW_SOCKET, SOCKET))
{
    my $name = gethostbyaddr ($client_addr, AF_INET);

    while (<NEW_SOCKET>)
    {
        print "Recieved from client: $_<<ENDL\n";
    }

    print NEW_SOCKET "Smile from the server.";

    print "Connection recieved from $name\n";

    close NEW_SOCKET or warn "Couldn't close socket: $!";
}
```

Full code for the client. Look for the `SEE HERE` comment.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Socket;

my $port = 8021;
my $proto = getprotobyname ('tcp');
my $server = "localhost";

$server = $ARGV[0] if (1 == @ARGV);

socket (SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
    or die "Can't create a socket: $!\n";

connect (SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in ($port, inet_aton ($server)))
    or die "Can't connect to $server:$port: $!\n";

# SEE HERE
#   my $s = select (SOCKET);
#   $| = 1; # make it hot
#   select ($s);
print SOCKET "Test message from client to $server:$port.";

shutdown (SOCKET, 1) or warn "Couldn't shutdown socket to $server:$port.";

while (<SOCKET>)
{
    print "Server $server:$port responds with: $_<<ENDL\n";
}

close SOCKET or die "Can't close socket to $server:$port: $!";
```

As it stands, the server outputs

```
Connection recieved from ANantes-256-1-226-50.w2-0.abo.wanadoo.fr
```

And the client outputs

```
Server localhost:8021 responds with: Smile from the server.<<ENDL
```

Clearly the client's `shutdown` command correctly causes the server's `while(<NEW_SOCKET>)` loop to exit, although the `Test message` which the client prints isn't read in that loop.

However, if I uncomment the lines below `SEE HERE`, the server prints the test message before sending its response.

**Surely when you `shutdown`, all pending data is supposed to be flushed, right?**

Why do I need the `$| = 1` line?

Also, can I *trust* the `$| = 1` line? As in, if I can't trust `shutdown` (or, presumably) `close` to not truncate messages, how can I trust `$|=1`?

Comment: What is `SERVER` in your server's `while`?  Please `use warnings`.

Comment: That was a typo, I fixed it, thanks, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to `while (<NEW_SOCKET>)` in the server and now both programs hang.

Comment: Okay, tinkering changed the scope of the question entirely. Please re-read it.

Comment: Can't get to it now but a bit later.  If this is about learning how to do it better use `IO::Socket`. Nicer and with many more examples around, for example [in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Sockets:-Client/Server-Communication)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical case of: [Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html). I recommend you to read the article if you are interested in more details.

> Surely when you shutdown, all pending data is supposed to be flushed, right?

That's not the case. If you check the perldoc of [shutdown](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shutdown.html), you won't find any hint about flushing. Also the man page of [shutdown(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shutdown.html) doesn't mention this behaviour at all.

The actual problem is the following line in your client code (see code comment):

```
...

socket (SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
    or die "Can't create a socket: $!\n";

connect (SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in ($port, inet_aton ($server)))
    or die "Can't connect to $server:$port: $!\n";

# Here is the problem
print SOCKET "Test message from client to $server:$port.";

shutdown (SOCKET, 1) or warn "Couldn't shutdown socket to $server:$port.";

...
```

The filehandle `SOCKET` is fully buffered, which means your data is not instantly printed to the network but gets accumulated in an internal buffer first. As soon as the internal buffer is filled, its data will be sent. The message you try to send by `print` is just a few bytes long - far from filling the internal buffer to its maximum size.

You already figured out how to modify the default buffering behaviour by using the special Perl variable `$|`. By changing the default value of this variable, you can make the currently active filehandle *hot*. That means the internal buffer will get flushed after every `print` to the filehandle.

Now let's see what different options you have to replace the problematic line mentioned above if you want to send the following message:

```
my $msg = "Test message from client to $server:$port.";
```

**Option #1:**

```
use FileHandle;
SOCKET->autoflush(1);
print SOCKET $msg;
```

You can use `autoflush()` from `FileHandle` to disable buffering of your `SOCKET` filehandle.

**Option #2:**

```
use IO::Handle; # or: use FileHandle
print SOCKET $msg;
SOCKET->flush();
```

You can also use the method `flush()` to manually flush after `print`.

**Option #3:**

```
{
    my $oldfh = select SOCKET;
    local $| = 1; # make SOCKET hot
    print SOCKET $msg;
    select $oldfh;
}
```

This selects the filehandle `SOCKET` to make it *hot* by setting `$|` to `1` in a local scope. After that your message `$msg` will be sent by `print` and the old filehandle gets restored by reselecting it. The old value of the global variable `$|` remains unaffected because we changed it only *locally* inside the `{ }` block.

**Option #4:**

```
syswrite SOCKET, $msg;
```

Furthermore you can simply use `syswrite()` to completely bypass the internal buffering.

**Option #5:**

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr => $server,
    PeerPort => $port,
    Proto    => "tcp"
);
$sock->send($msg);
```

This is simple and straightforward to use and replaces almost all of your code. According to the documentation of [`IO::Socket`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Socket.pm):

> As of VERSION 1.18 all IO::Socket objects have **autoflush turned on** by default. This was not the case with earlier releases.

All of these 5 options will give you the behaviour you are looking for.